# Making decisions from a menu

Tags: c#

this is my first post and my first semester in C#.  I have a homework assignment that I've been working on for days and I can't figure it out.  I'm going to try to explain it as best as I can.

So I have to create a class to call two other class and compile the classes to print.  The user is suppose to select a number from the menu and that number is suppose to do a math operation and print the answer.  I can't get the code to produce the selection and perform the math operation.

Here is my first class.

```
class MainModule
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string assignment = "Assignment#3B-Math Operations Modified";

        MathOperationUI myNumber = new MathOperationUI();
        myNumber.MathMainModule();

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is my second class.

```
class MathOperations
{
    int firstOperand;
    int secondOperand;

    public int FirstOperand
    {
        get
        {
            return firstOperand;
        }
        set
        {
            firstOperand = value;
        }
    }

    public int SecondOperand
    {
        get
        {
            return secondOperand;
        }
        set
        {
            secondOperand = value;
        }
    }

    public MathOperations()
    {
        firstOperand = 0;
        secondOperand = 0;
    }

    public double Add()
    {
        double theAddition;
        theAddition = (firstOperand + secondOperand);
        return theAddition;
    }

    public double Subtract()
    {
        double theSubtraction;
        theSubtraction = (firstOperand - secondOperand);
        return theSubtraction;
    }

    public double Multiply()
    {
        double theMultiplication;
        theMultiplication = (firstOperand * secondOperand);
        return theMultiplication;
    }

    public double Divide()
    {
        double theDivision;
        theDivision = (float)firstOperand / (float)secondOperand;
        return theDivision;
```

And my last class that's giving me the problem.

```
class MathOperationUI
{
    public MathOperationUI()
    {
    }
    public void MathMainModule()
    {
        int firstOperand;
        int secondOperand;

        DisplayMenu();         

        MathOperations usersMathOperations;

        firstOperand = PromptForInterger("first");
        secondOperand = PromptForInterger("second");

        usersMathOperations = new MathOperations ();
    }

    public void DisplayMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\tMenu");
        Console.WriteLine("****************************");
        Console.WriteLine("1: Addition Operation");
        Console.WriteLine("2: Subtraction Operation");
        Console.WriteLine("3: Multiplication Operation");
        Console.WriteLine("4: Division Operation");
        Console.WriteLine("5: Exit");
        Console.WriteLine("****************************");
    }

    static int ProcessMenu(int choice)
    {
        if (choice == 1)
            Console.WriteLine("\nWhen adding the number {0} and {1}, the answer is {2}", myNumber.FirstOperand, myNumber.SecondOperand, addition);
        else
            if (choice == 2)
                Console.WriteLine("\nWhen subtracting the number {0} and {1}, the answer is {2}", myNumber.FirstOperand, myNumber.SecondOperand, subtraction);
            else
                if (choice == 3)
                    Console.WriteLine("\nWhen multipling the number {0} and {1}, the answer is {2}", myNumber.FirstOperand, myNumber.SecondOperand, multiplication);
                else
                    if (choice == 4)
                        Console.WriteLine("\nWhen dividing the number {0} and {1}, the answer is {2:F2}", myNumber.FirstOperand, myNumber.SecondOperand, division);
                    else
                        if (choice == 5)
                            return 0;
    }

    static int PromptForInterger(string position)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nEnter the {0} number:\t", position);
        return (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you just quit coding when you got into trouble.  You need to remove *static* from the ProcessMenu() method to get ahead.

Comment: I'm still working on it.  I removed static and nothing changed.  I'm getting an error "The name 'myNumber' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

myNumber does not exist in the current context because it should either exists in ProcessMenu function of it should exist in a global/instance context. You are in the right track but you are missing some points. Declare a MathOperations object as intance variable in your MathOperationsUI class than in MathMainModule set FirstOperand and SecondOperand of that object and call ProcessMenu. In Process menu instead of using myNumber use the object you declared as instance variable (MathOperations), and call its appropriate functions (add,multiply etc) Let me know if you get it working. I have a working version I will post it if you can't get it.

This below can only be accessed in main method because that is where it is declared. If it is declared in a method it can only be accessed in that method unless you pass it as a parameter to another method.

```
 MathOperationUI myNumber = new MathOperationUI();
```

Besides you dont want to call `myNumber.FirstOperand` because myNumber is a MathOperationUI type however FirstOperand is in MathOperations not in ..UI.

Your MathOperationUI should look like below. A MathOperations object that is declared in a class (MathOperationUI) but outside of any method. This means that you can access this object from any method within MathOperationUI. Then you should set the properties of MathOperations (First and Second Operand) with the user input from PromptForInterger. Finally you should call the ProcessMenu method to process those inputs.

```
public class MathOperationUI
{
    MathOperations usersMathOperations;

    public MathOperationUI()
    {
        usersMathOperations = new MathOperations();
    }

    public void MathMainModule()
    {
        DisplayMenu();
        usersMathOperations.FirstOperand = PromptForInterger("first");
        usersMathOperations.SecondOperand = PromptForInterger("second");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nEnter your coice");
        ProcessMenu(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    }
```

Now you can access this object from the process method. And you can get its first and second operand and call the Add, Multiply etc. methods.

```
Console.WriteLine("\nWhen adding the number {0} and {1}, the answer is {2}", usersMathOperations.FirstOperand, usersMathOperations.SecondOperand, usersMathOperations.Add());
```

Finally here is the piece that is working  https://dotnetfiddle.net/5lE63L

Hope this makes things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are having problems implementing a couple of aspects of programming:

- Scope - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Expression_scope
- Value assignment - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29

Scope is particularly important and will influence almost every line of code you ever write.

Perhaps you could ask your tutor to go through these concepts again for you?

*(This is not exactly a solution, as I am reluctant to simply give you the answer to your homework. But it hopefully points you in the right direction.)*